# EOF error using input Python 3

Tags: input, pycharm, eof

I keep getting an EOF error but unsure as to why. I have tried with and without int() but it makes no difference. I'm using Pycharm 3.4 and Python 3.

Thanks,
Chris

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("what's your favourite number?"))
        print (number)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You must close a [try statement](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) because you are declaring that there might be an error and you want to handle it

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("what's your favourite number?"))
        print(number)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Woah, there is an error: {0}".format(e))
```